# migration from svn to git 2.9.2 on windows

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Migration from svn (server version 1.6.11) to git (version 2.9.2) on Windows 10 doesn't seem to work as described (I want to keep all svn-tags and branches).

**First try:**

I followed the tutorial provided at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-convert.

Result: all branches are deleted, when the following command is executed:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar ~/svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git 
--force
```

**Next try:**

I followed the steps described at https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git:

- checkout the project: `git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=authors.txt --no-metadata  http://<the-svn-url-without-trunk>  <module-directory>`
- After checking out the command `git tag -l` produces empty output.
- `git branch -a` produces the following output (as expected):

  `*master
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.0
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.1
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.2
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.1.0
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.2.0
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.3.0
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.4.0
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.4.1
    remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.5.0
    remotes/origin/trunk`

The next step according to the documentation:

```
To move the tags to be proper Git tags, run

$ cp -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/tags/* .git/refs/tags/
$ rm -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/tags
```

The problem:

The path `.git/refs/remotes/origin/tags/` is empty. All the svn-tags seem to be located at

```
.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/tags
```

The directory `.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/tags` contained a subdirectory for each tag. I tried to move these directories to `.git/refs/tags/`but this leads to the following output, when executing `git branch -a`:

`warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.0/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.0/unhandled.log
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.1/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.1/unhandled.log
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.2/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.2/unhandled.log
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.1.0/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.1.0/unhandled.log
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.2.0/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.2.0/unhandled.log
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.3.0/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.3.0/unhandled.log
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.4.0/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.4.0/unhandled.log
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.4.1/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.4.1/unhandled.log
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.5.0/index
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.5.0/unhandled.log
* master
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.0
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.1
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.0.2
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.1.0
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.2.0
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.3.0
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.4.0
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.4.1
  remotes/origin/tags/de-vgwort-jerry-configuration-1.5.0
  remotes/origin/trunk`

**Next try**

Use svn2git from https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git. But this tool doesn't seem to work either. After running

```
svn2git <svn-url-without-trunk> --authors ..\authors.txt
```

the command `git branch -a` produced the following output:

`* master
  remotes/svn/trunk`

=> This result is quite useless.

What am I missing here? Is there any documentation applicable for Windows and the latest git version 2.9.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-way import, you can try [subgit import](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#7)

[SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) has a free offer for import, and it generally is more complete than [`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: subgit import works fine (and much faster than git svn).

Thanks for the help.